# How to remove duplicates in R

Tags: r

I have a very large data set, and it looks like this one below:
`df <- data.frame(school=c("a", "a", "a", "b","b","c","c","c"), year=c(3,3,1,4,2,4,3,1), GPA=c(4,4,4,3,3,3,2,2))`

```
school year GPA
  a    3   4
  a    3   4
  a    1   4
  b    4   3
  b    2   3
  c    4   3
  c    3   2
  c    1   2
```

and I want it to be look like:

```
school year GPA
 a    3   4
 a    3   4
 b    4   3
 c    4   3
```

So basically, what I want is for each given school, I want their top year student(students), regardless of the GPA.

I have tried:

`new_df <- df[!duplicated(paste(df[,1],df[,2])),]`
but this gives me the unique combination between the school and year.

while the one below gives me the unique school
`new_df2 <- df[!duplicated(df$school),]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `plyr` library

```
require(plyr)
ddply(df,.(school),function(x){x[x$year==max(x$year),]})
> ddply(df,.(school),function(x){x[x$year==max(x$year),]})
  school year GPA
1      a    3   4
2      a    3   4
3      b    4   3
4      c    4   3
```

or base

```
test<-lapply(split(df,df$school),function(x){x[x$year==max(x$year),]})
out<-do.call(rbind,test)
> out
    school year GPA
a.1      a    3   4
a.2      a    3   4
b        b    4   3
c        c    4   3
```

Explanation:
`split` splits the dataframe into a list by schools.

```
dat<-split(df,df$school)

> dat
$a
  school year GPA
1      a    3   4
2      a    3   4
3      a    1   4

$b
  school year GPA
4      b    4   3
5      b    2   3

$c
  school year GPA
6      c    4   3
7      c    3   2
8      c    1   2
```

for each school we want the members in the top year.

```
dum.fun<-function(x){x[x$year==max(x$year),]}

> dum.fun(dat$a)
  school year GPA
1      a    3   4
2      a    3   4
```

`lapply` applies a function over the members of a list and outputs a list

```
> lapply(split(df,df$school),function(x){x[x$year==max(x$year),]})
$a
  school year GPA
1      a    3   4
2      a    3   4

$b
  school year GPA
4      b    4   3

$c
  school year GPA
6      c    4   3
```

this is what we want but in list form. We need to bind the members of the list together. We do this by calling `rbind` on the members successively using `do.call`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a fan of the `by` statement (see `?by`) for this kind of thing. `df` is split into groups on the basis of `df$school` and then the rows of each school which represent the `max(year)` are returned.

```
> by(df,df$school,function(x) x[x$year==max(x$year),])
df$school: a
  school year GPA
1      a    3   4
2      a    3   4
------------------------------------------------------------ 
df$school: b
  school year GPA
4      b    4   3
------------------------------------------------------------ 
df$school: c
  school year GPA
6      c    4   3
```

`do.call(rbind...` just joins up the results for each school which are returned from the `by` statement.

```
do.call(rbind,by(df,df$school,function(x) x[x$year==max(x$year),]))

    school year GPA
a.1      a    3   4
a.2      a    3   4
b        b    4   3
c        c    4   3
```

Comment: @ttmaccer - it seems to be an underused R function considering how useful it is. The trap I fell into as a newbie when I first came across it was not realising that it's output was just a normal `list`.

Comment: Thanks for your input as well. theletemail